# How to take an action when all ajax calls in each loop success?

Tags: ajax, jquery

I call ajax jquery function inside .each loop, and I want to do an action just when all the ajax calls inside the loop finish and success.

```
$(".checked-box").each(function () {
     // ajax call goes here
});
$('.messsage').html('all requests done');
```

How to do that? without `async: false` because this blocks the browser.

Comment: do you want to know after each ajax call or you want after all the calls are done in the loop

Comment: all calls are done in the loop

Comment: check out the jquery deferred. Mostly this with combination of jquery.when([deferreds]) will help. http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one way:

```
var numberOfPendingRequests = 8;
$(".checked-box").each(function () {   
   $.ajax({
     success: function(){
        ...
        numberOfPendingRequests --;
        if(numberOfPendingRequests == 0) allDone();
     }
   });
});
function allDone(){
  $('.messsage').html('all requests done');
}
```

You can calculate the initial `numberOfPendingRequests` based on your number of checkboxes or start it at 0 an increment it before each ajax request, but this is the general idea.

Hope this helps. Cheers

Answer (score 8):

Deferreds can make your work simpler.

```
var deferreds = $('.checked-box').map(function(i, elem) {
  return $.ajax(params);
});

$.when.apply(null, deferreds.get()).then(function() { ... });
```

Hope this should work.

The concept is

```
$.when(
    $.ajax( "1" ),
    $.ajax( "2" ),
    $.ajax( "3" )
).then( successFunc, failureFunc );
```

Comment: seams good, while I am not familiar yet with Deferreds, for example if I put my .each loop inside this .when it will work? and will get the ajax success response?

Comment: the success function in ajax is something like deferred only. it is called once that particular request has responded. you can do whatever you want to do there in success .. i.e. after each ajax response. I havent tested the code with each. Mostly the above code should work. I ll test it and post the edit later.

Comment: I tested it with .each, it didn't wait till all the loop done, the then ran before :(

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
AjaxRequestCount = 0;
//JUST prepare ajax requests here, do not send yet...
$(".checked-box").each(function () {
     AjaxRequestCount += 1; //Count number of ajax request
     //set "success:" of each ajax to Success() function
});

//Send ajax requests here, use a loop...

for(i=0;i<AjaxRequestCount;i++)
{
   //ajax[i].send
} 

//Fires for each ajax success...
function Success()
{
    SuccessAjaxRequestCount += 1;
    Check(); //Check right after each ajax success
}

//Checks if already reached the expected number of ajax success...
function Check()
{
    if(SuccessAjaxRequestCount  == AjaxRequestCount )
    {
        alert("done!");
    }
}
```

Comment: It worked for me, and It showed the alert once at the end of the loop and all ajax calls.

Comment: Yeah, I made an error, now I add a loop that will send ajax request after ajax preparation so that it `success:` of each ajax wont fire until all ajax are prepared to be sent.

Comment: @amr , he modified code after my comment , anyway thats kool it works

Comment: @Amr - You might encounter a problem like kobe, how if the ajax receives a successful response prior to sending of the ajax next to it? `SuccessAjaxRequestCount  == AjaxRequestCount` will be true, alert will pop-up! Please see revisions. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

look at section 3.1 of [this post](http://blog.mixu.net/2011/02/02/essential-node-js-patterns-and-snippets/) for a complete example of waiting for asynchronous stuff to end